# Giving www-data access to i2c

Tags: apache-httpd, php, i2c

I have a light sensor that uses I2C for data transmision. Now I want to display that data on a Website.

The problem is `www-data` can't access I2C. I use a Python script that gets run by PHP (I know it's not the best idea) and it throws

```
ERROR: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"
```

I tried giving the script 777 and gave the file to `www-data`. Nothing changed.

What can I do?

Comment: what mechanism does your python script use to access i2c?

Comment: I use smbus, but the python script isn't the problem shouldn't

Comment: Without knowing knowing the specifics of what you are doing on what locations, it seems like you need to be able to give permission to the `i2c` bus for the apache user `www-data`. If you haven't already attempted something like this you might check out:
https://lexruee.ch/setting-i2c-permissions-for-non-root-users.html